# Static reference and using Objects which have been initialized outside of a main?

Tags: java, object, methods, static, non-static

I have a question concerning the use of objects...

I have a class called Area which contains a few methods. I want to access these methods in another class in which an Area object is created.

```
public class calcAreaObj {
Area areaObj = new Area();

public static void main(String[] args){
            areaObj.area(2,3,4);

}

}
```

Why is it when the class is created as above I get an error("Cannot make a static reference to non-static field areaObj. But when the source code is written such that the Area object is initiaized inside the main statement as below there are no errors...

```
public class calcAreaObj {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Area areaObj = new Area();
    areaObj.area(2,3,4);
}

}
```

Is this because in the first case the Area object is initialized outside of a static statement? If so, why does this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when defined at class scope, `areaObj` is specific to each instance of `calcAreaObj`. That's not really what you want, since `main` is a static method (and so doesn't have an *instance* of `calcAreaObj` associated with it). You can either use the second code sample you posted, or you can modify the first one as follows:

```
public class calcAreaObj {
static Area areaObj = new Area();

public static void main(String[] args){
            areaObj.area(2,3,4);

}

}
```

Additionally, if `areaObj` doesn't have any state, in this case, you could always declare `Area.area` as static.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example `areaObj` is a non-static member of `calcAreaObj`. This means it can only be accessed using an instance of `calcAreaObj`.

```
new calcAreaObj().areaObj.whatever(); //this will work
calcAreaObj.areaObj; //areaObj isn't a static member, won't work
```

In short: the non-static member doesn't even exist as long as you haven't created an instance of `calcAreaObj`. In the second example, it's in scope of the method and thus accessible.

Answer (score 0):

For the first situation your creating a local variable for the class which has no relation with the object used in the main. Therefore you have to initialize the object again in the main.

There is a rule: that any block has it's own variables. So if you initialize a variable in block and try to use it outside the block that will give you an error.

For example:

```
public static void main(String [] arg){

{ Area a = new Area(); }

double number = a.area

}
```

this doesn't work ...

I wish it is clear